# Prove $\left \langle \nabla f(p), p \right \rangle = \kappa f(p)$ for homogenous $f$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \left \{ 0 \right \} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.
>
> Prove that $f$ is homogenous of order $\kappa$ ($\forall t>0, p\in D: f(tp)=t^{\kappa}f(p)$) if and only if $\forall p \in D$, $\left \langle \nabla f(p), p \right \rangle = \kappa f(p)$

Not sure what to do, ideas are welcome.

Comment: note it is $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^m$. my bad.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231343/gradient-of-a-homogenous-function#:~:text=A%20function%20f%3ARn,%3Dkf(x).